# How can the value referenced by a variable of type float array have type byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

The NAudio library provides the following interface.

```
interface ISampleProvider
{
    WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; }
    int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}
```

I made a class that implements this interface. In my implementation of `Read` I am getting very strange behavior. The type of the `buffer` argument is showing up as `byte[]` even though that variable is declared to be a `float[]`.

```
    int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //The type of buffer is System.Byte[]!
        var type = buffer.GetType();
        ...
    }
```

How can this be?

I don't know how the NAudio library is calling my `Read` implementation, but I'm guessing it may be via some unsafe interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the `WaveBuffer` class in action, which is a way that NAudio tricks .NET into letting us "cast" a `byte[]` into a `float[]` without having to copy data or pin buffers.

Read more about it:

- [WaveBuffer - Casting Byte Arrays to Float Arrays](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/wavebuffer-casting-byte-arrays-to-float.html)
- [How to convert byte[] to short[] or float[] arrays in C#](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-convert-byte-to-short-or-float.html)